# SPARC T4 iLom CLI not accessible from SER MGT Port. (NET MGT - inaccessible)

Tags: sparc, sunos, sun

Our 3 SPARC T4 Sun servers have all of a sudden began the exact same behaviour.
-Fans are at full RPM
-Attentions lights on all 3 are on solid amber
-ILOM network interfaces not responding (all 3 were working fine previously)
-When connecting to the SER MGT port i am getting the Local Solaris OS clie not sp(hadn't tried accessing it previously this way but all online documents state this should be a direct cli to ILOM.)

I am out of ideas and power cycling the machines is absolutely out of the question.

Comment: Using prtdiag (possibly with -v) from a root shell should give you an indication of the system's idea of hardware health (including temperature). Doesn't help with access to out-of-band management port but might give pointer to what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You ran into a firmware bug. There is a fix in recent firmware releases.

When the NET MGT ports get some weird malformed packets the ILOM crashes and goes into bypass mode:
temp sensors are offline, so fans go to full speed
SER MGT switches to pass through to Solaris serial port

You need to power cycle the boxes (pull the plug, wait 30s, plug in)
Update the firmware

Then you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the Solaris CLI because the ILOM is connecting you to it, i.e. passing you through. Try the escape sequence to get back to the ILOM. The escape sequence is the ESC key and "(" (open parentheses without the quotes). If that works, you should be able to get the ILOM to tell you the status of the hardware. As far as the hardware goes, I'm guessing you're having an over heating issue. If the temp in the room is high, fix that. If room temp is fine, call Oracle.